# How to avoid a trailing comma in a comma-separated error list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, error-handling

I'm trying to create a comma-separated list. I want to make sure that the last line won't have a comma at the end.

This is what I have so far without any commas just the data:

```
var labelText = $(this).attr("placeholder");
$('div.errors').append(''+labelText+' Required');
```

Not sure if I should use the map() function for this or do some sort of if statement?

Comment: Where are the CSVs coming from?

Comment: @BradChristie a contact form

Comment: @ftntravis: How about `[val1, val2, val3].join(',')`?

Comment: You don't need the `''+` in `.append(''+labelText+' Required');`

Comment: Is the code you show in a loop, or...? What is `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var colors = ["Orange", "Blue", "Red", "Green"];
var string = colors.join(); // Orange, Blue, Red, Green
```

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing the rest of your code you could have a variable

```
var errorComma = ""; //Initialized to blank
```

Then inside the code that does the append

```
var labelText = $(this).attr("placeholder");
$('div.errors').append(errorComma +labelText+' Required');
errorComma =",";
```

Thus the first call would have an empty string in the comma location, and all subsequent calls would include the comma.